# @PrePersist convert date to UTC?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, wildfly

I am using WildFly, (jboss-javaee-7.0-with-hibernate), JPA(hibernate-jpa-2.1-api), hibernate-jpamodelgen and MySql as Database. Can anyone please guide me how can I store a date in UTC format using @PrePersist or @PreUpdate or some other way.

Sample Model Class:

```
@Entity
@Audited
@XmlRootElement
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "name"))
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "handler", "hibernateLazyInitializer" })
public class SampleTest {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String name;

    private String comment;

    private Date createdDate;

    private Date lastModifiedDate;

    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        createdDate = new Date();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    protected void onUpdate() {
        lastModifiedDate = new Date();
    }
```

This doesn't store the created Date and Last Modified Date in UTC timezone in Database. Can someone please guide me?

Comment: You should consider using `java.sql.Timestamp` in your POJO, and convert that to/from the appropriate `java.time` class.

Comment: Hibernate 5, if you can use it, also has support for the Java 8 Date-Time API.

Comment: Have you tried using `java.sql.Date`? "A thin wrapper around a millisecond value that allows JDBC to identify this as an SQL DATE value. A milliseconds value represents the number of milliseconds that have passed since January 1, 1970 00:00:00.000 GMT.

"